# Error: class or style file required by it is not available

Tags: lyx, installing, ubuntu, apa-style

I'm new to Latex. I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit with Lyx 1.6.7. I had created a modified APA template for school. It works on my Windows XP and Mac OSX systems. But in the Ubuntu system I get an error (below). Even when I try to open any of the pre-built templates I get the error. Any ideas on how to fix this? I tried a reinstall through the Ubuntu Software Center, but it didn't fix anything.

> ERROR:
>   The layout file requested by this document,
>   apa.layout,
>   is not usable. This is probably because a LaTeX
>   class or style file required by it is not
>   available. See the Customization documentation
>   for more information.
>   LyX will not be able to produce output.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Install the [`apa`](http://ctan.org/pkg/apa) package.

- If you installed TeX from the Ubuntu repositories, you could install the package `texlive-publishers` which contains `apa`, using the Ubuntu package manager (Synaptic).
- Otherwise, if possible, use the TeX Live Manager aka tlmgr.
- Or load it from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/apa) and install it.